# win32com (python) error

Tags: python, win32com, notepad

i am trying to automate a action in notepad for a program im working on and i cant figure out an error message i am getting.

```
import os
import win32com

object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Notepad.Application")
```

error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   1, in    File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 95,
>   in Dispatch
>       dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104,
>   in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
>       return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84,
>   in _GetGoodDispatch
>       IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch) com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class
>   string', None, None)
>   any help?

Comment: Are you sure that (1) Notepad is a COM server, and (2) its ProgID is Notepad.Application?

Answer (score 3):

Notepad has no COM interface that I can Find. Try using pywinauto. Check [this](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?fromSeriesID=7&name=UsingpyWinAutoToControlAWindowsApplication) video to see how it works.

Comment: @Jon Crawley. If you like the answer, please except it.