# Error message trying to execute AutoIT script in Python

Tags: python, autoit

Hello I'm trying to automate a file drop process and here's my Python script, with AutoIT imported via the `win32com` module

```
from selenium import webdriver
import win32com.client

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://tinyjpg.com/")
assert "TinyJPG" in driver.title

droplocation = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon")
droplocation.click()
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
autoit.Run(r"filedrop.exe")
```

However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tea\Desktop\compressimg.py", line 30, in <module>
    autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

The most similar post I could find was this: [win32com (python) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446844/win32com-python-error), but I think websites are supposed to be COM servers so that's not really relevant here?

In any case, I'm not too sure what the error is trying to tell me, help is appreciated!

Comment: `reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoItX3.Control`. Run that command at a command prompt. If you get an error then you may need the register the AutoIt DLLs. `AutoItX3.dll` for x86 and `AutoItX3_x64.dll` for x64. The COM server you mention operates in the OS. You can use `regsvr32.exe` to register the DLLs if needed.

Comment: @michael_heath thanks for the suggestion! but I just checked and I already have all the AutoItX3.dll files required. Seems like that's not the issue :/